# How to deal with ambiguity when editing posts

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207882/which-reporting-tool-i-should-use-birt-or-jasper) from 2013 was recently put on hold because it's asking for a tool recommendation. [One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16209195/4070984) has, as I see it, two problems: it contains a dead link, and it reads like a sales pitch. I submitted an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11607499) to fix these problems, which was rejected, by three votes to two, for deviating from the original intent of the post.

I assume the reason for the rejection was the following: the unedited post begins with "I would suggest Jasper not because I am working on it but because", which I understood as a disclosure that the answerer was working on Jasper; in my edit I converted this into a separate disclosure. As the reviewers (I assume) rightly noticed, though, there's an ambiguity here - it's possible that the answerer wants to state that they are *not* working on Jasper, in which case the disclosure added by my edit would be wrong. In that case, though, the "not because I am working on it" contains no useful information and can (I assume) be removed entirely.

What, then, is the correct way to deal with a clause such as "not because I am working on it", which may or may not, ambiguously, be conveying important information? Or is the premise of my question entirely wrong - should sales-pitch-like answers be left with their original wording, provided they don't amount to spam?

Comment: I think the generic advice would be not to worry about answers to low-quality, closed questions. This question is likely to be deleted soon, making any edits to answers rather pointless.

Comment: As CodyGray said, it will be deleted soon, whether automatically by the roomba or manually (2/3 delete-votes are already there, what a waste)..